# How to open a link with only a keyboard on Google Docs

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-docs, accessibility

I wanted to know if anyone have any experience with using Google Docs with only a keyboard? How do I open a link there? The only solution I could find was to use Microsoft’s MouseKeys option but it’s very cumbersome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This now works in a Google Doc:

Hold <kbd>option</kbd> and press <kbd>return</kbd> key with cursor beside link; position cursor before, within or after link using arrow keys + <kbd>option</kbd> key to skip words.

Comment: This is the answer for macOS, us ALT instead on Windows/PC answer as noted by Gerald.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is for Macs.  To open a hyperlink in a Google Doc on a **PC keyboard**:

1. Place your cursor either at..

   - the beginning of the hyperlink
   - somewhere inside the hyperlink text
   - at the end of the hyperlink
2. Press the ALT + ENTER keys

Answer (score 3):

On `https://docs.google.com/`, when you’re connected, type <kbd>?</kbd> (probably <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>), it will show you some keyboard shortcuts.

You can select a document with <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrows then press `enter`

When you are in an editing mode (ie. spreadsheet), click on “Help > Keyboard Shortcuts.”

Comment: Ok - after searching the available keyboard shortcuts, I found that in a spreadsheet you *can* open a link by pressing `alt+enter`but I still couldn't find any way to do it in a google doc... +1 for the spreadsheet solution

Comment: I found a funny way :
Place your cursor on the link, then use the shortcut `Insert link` (`Command` + `K` for Mac OS X), then your focus will be on the textfield with url, so you can copy/paste it to a new tab url's bar :)

Comment: You also need to watch for messages from the browsers' pop-up blocker (and allow pop-ups to be opened from within google drive /google docs)

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Spreadsheet on Mac OS, press <kbd>Options</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the cell contains hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

For me (using Mac), <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> opened the link in a new window.
However I found that <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> opened the link in a new tab (on Safari, at least).